# Could someone create a "petanque" tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I have a question about my Sports Stack Exchange post: [Differences between leisure and competition boules in petanque](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/differences-between-leisure-and-competition-boules-in-petanque)

I wanted to tag this question with "petanque" but no such tag exists & I don't have enough reputation points to do it. Could someone else create a "petanque" tag? Petanque is a well-established international sport, with players and national, continental, and international federations in countries all over the world. (fipjp.org). In English-speaking countries, there are well-established communities of players in England, Australia, New Zealand, the USA, and Canada.

Answer (score 4):

According to the timestamps, I'd already created the "[petanque](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/petanque)" tag sixteen minutes before you posted this, having seen your post on MSE.

Your final paragraph ("Petanque is a well-established international sport...") seems to imply that petanque should have had a tag already, so I'll quickly address why it didn't: tags on Stack Exchange are created as and when they're needed, so as not to clutter the system with loads of tags that never get used. Nobody had asked a petanque question before, therefore there was no need for one until now.

Answer (score -2):

Two comments here, if I can coalesce my thoughts enough.

First, why do we need a Petanque tag at all. There is currently only one tagged question. Search for the name "petanque" and you'll find it. We need tags when we need a good way to help someone track a subject. I'm not suggesting we remove the tag, but just asking for a tag for any sport one person is interested in, for one (or even two) questions will lead to too many (mostly unused) tags.

Second, why do we need a Petanque tag at all, in that that is one derivative of a class of (lawn) bowling sports. If I post a Bocce question, I will want a Bocce tag. Not a Petanque tag. Do we make tags for, literally, every ... single ... derivative sport?

Now, I am going to play devil's advocate to my own comments.

First, why not. Let's make tags for every sport possible. That way if a person posts a question about a very unknown and little played sport, then they'll have a tag to be able to track it. Just because (originally, in the early days of SE) they don't want too many tags, doesn't mean we can't buck that unwritten rule and make several hundred tags.

Second, why not. Let's make a Petanque tag: done. New let's make a Bocce tag, and then a Lawn Bowling, and a Basque Bowls, and a Boccia and a Boules, and every other form or variant of Bowls, and then make a Bowls tag as a synonym for them all.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be engaging sensibly with the question. In particular, why bring up sports which have no questions to put them on? Why state that bowls should be a synonym of them all? (both of these things are impossible in the system, by the way). Tags are for helping identify categories of questions; individual sports are established as categories; petanque is a sport and there is a question about it; there is no reason not to have the tag.